# Disable user input with `apt-get install -y r-base`when build a dockerfile

Tags: r, docker, ubuntu

When building a docker file, even with the `ENV DEDIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`, `apt-get install r-base` still prompts the following user inputs that prevent the automatic build process. Is there any way to disable these user inputs? Or, setting them through a `config` file?
[image: Geographic area]
[image: city or region]
The minimal `Dockerfile` is

```
# Use an official Ubuntu runtime as a parent image
FROM ubuntu:24.04

# Set environment variable to avoid interactive prompts
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Update the package lists and install a package without prompts
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y r-base
```

I tried on macOS(m1) with Docker version 25.0.1 and macOS(intel) with Docker version 20.10.17.

Comment: It seems likely that this could be related to locale. I just build this dockerfile unchanged and it did not prompt me for anything. (I'm in the USA, my laptop is set to English. Perhaps also related: I'm building it on a Ubuntu system.)

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the info. It may be related to OS, I am in the USA, build it on macOS.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Note that this _exact_ APT/`tzdata` prompt is described in [How to fill user input for interactive command for "RUN" command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59692797/how-to-fill-user-input-for-interactive-command-for-run-command), but setting `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add --no-install-recommends I believe.

```
# Use an official Ubuntu runtime as a parent image
FROM ubuntu:24.04

# Set environment variable to avoid interactive prompts
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Update the package lists and install a package without prompts and recommends
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends r-base
```

Plus I would suggest to use rocker (R image for docker) in general

```
# Base R image
FROM rocker/r-ver
#easier and less hussle
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip of `rocker/r-ver`, it is very helpful