# Install EnergyPlus in. Docker Image

Tags: docker, energyplus

I am attempting to install [EnergyPlus](https://github.com/NREL/EnergyPlus/releases/tag/v24.1.0) in a Docker Image, but getting stuck a the license acceptance during the docker build step?

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

# wget
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget 
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Download the EnergyPlus Install Script
RUN wget https://github.com/NREL/EnergyPlus/releases/download/v24.1.0/EnergyPlus-24.1.0-9d7789a3ac-Linux-Ubuntu22.04-x86_64.sh

# Make the EnergyPlus Install Script executable
RUN chmod +x EnergyPlus-24.1.0-9d7789a3ac-Linux-Ubuntu22.04-x86_64.sh

# Run the E+ Install Script
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN ./EnergyPlus-24.1.0-9d7789a3ac-Linux-Ubuntu22.04-x86_64.sh
```

which all works, except that it gets hung up on the `Do you accept the license? [y/N]:` during the EnergyPlus installation.

I have reviewed the similar questions:

- [How to fill user input for interactive command for "RUN" command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59692797/how-to-fill-user-input-for-interactive-command-for-run-command)
- [How to install tzdata on a ubuntu docker image?](https://serverfault.com/questions/949991/how-to-install-tzdata-on-a-ubuntu-docker-image/992421#992421)

and have not found the answers there helpful in understanding how to solve my case here.

Is there a method for answering 'Y' during the Install? Note that after inputting 'Y', I then also have to enter 'Return' to confirm the default folder location as well? Is it possible to provide a series of different response values ("Y", "Return", ...) during the install like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expect is a handy tool for handling interactive CLI applications.

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        wget \
        expect \
        libgomp1 \
        libx11-6 && \ 
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN wget https://github.com/NREL/EnergyPlus/releases/download/v24.1.0/EnergyPlus-24.1.0-9d7789a3ac-Linux-Ubuntu22.04-x86_64.sh

COPY install.exp .

RUN chmod +x EnergyPlus-24.1.0-9d7789a3ac-Linux-Ubuntu22.04-x86_64.sh

RUN expect install.exp

CMD EnergyPlus -v
```

You also need to install a couple of libraries to satisfy the dependencies of `EnergyPlus`. I have added those to the `apt-get install` command.

The `CMD` is just to illustrate the the install was successful (see screenshot). You can obviously remove this.

`install.exp`

```
set timeout 120

spawn ./EnergyPlus-24.1.0-9d7789a3ac-Linux-Ubuntu22.04-x86_64.sh

expect -re {Do you accept the license.*:}
send "y\r"

expect -re {EnergyPlus install directory.*}
send "\r"

expect -re {Symbolic link location.*}
send "\r"

expect eof
```

[image]